# Django 1.11 don't load static image and show error in main page

Tags: python, django

I have a new problem:
I don't know what is the problem, because I check it move the folder media to eventus folder, but it no working, and I change the path in MEDIA_URL, but it no working too.

I think the problem will be in that I follow a tutorial of the version 1.6 of Django and some things are deferents in this new version and I don't know how to do it.

[image]

my schema of the project is the next

```
.
├── eventus
│   ├── eventus
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── db.sqlite3
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   │   ├── base.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   │   └── local.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── local.py
│   │   │   ├── prod.py
│   │   │   └── staging.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── myapps
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── events
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── forms.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   ├── admin.py
│       │   ├── apps.py
│       │   ├── forms.py
│       │   ├── media
│       │   │   └── events
│       │   │       ├── evento.png
│       │   │       ├── evento2.png
│       │   │       ├── evento2_a0yEovu.png
│       │   │       ├── evento3.png
│       │   │       ├── evento3_IufcnS5.png
│       │   │       └── evento_HFKQ1lo.png
│       │   ├── migrations
│       │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│       │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2140.py
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   └── __pycache__
│       │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2115.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2140.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   ├── models.py
│       │   ├── static
│       │   │   ├── css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│       │   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│       │   │   │   └── estilos.css
│       │   │   ├── fonts
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│       │   │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│       │   │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│       │   │   └── js
│       │   │       ├── bootstrap.js
│       │   │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       │   │       └── npm.js
│       │   ├── templates
│       │   │   ├── base.html
│       │   │   └── events
│       │   │       ├── base_events.html
│       │   │       ├── index.html
│       │   │       └── panel
│       │   │           ├── crear_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── detalle_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── editar_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── eliminar_evento.html
│       │   │           ├── navbar.html
│       │   │           └── panel.html
│       │   ├── tests.py
│       │   ├── urls.py
│       │   └── views.py
│       └── users
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── __pycache__
│           │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── actions.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   └── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│           ├── actions.py
│           ├── admin.py
│           ├── apps.py
│           ├── forms.py
│           ├── migrations
│           │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│           │   ├── __init__.py
│           │   └── __pycache__
│           │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│           │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│           ├── models.py
│           ├── templates
│           │   └── users
│           │       └── login.html
│           ├── tests.py
│           ├── urls.py
│           └── views.py
└── requirements
    ├── base.txt
    ├── local.txt
    ├── prod.txt
    └── staging.txt

27 directories, 94 files
```

And I change the configuration of this archives:
my file urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import  url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('myapps.events.urls', namespace="events_app")),
    url(r'^', include('myapps.users.urls', namespace="users_app")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [

        ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my file users/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import  url, include


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', 'myapps.users.views.userlogin', name="login"),
    ]
```

my file users/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
# Create your views here.

def userlogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST": 
        pass
    else:
        user_register = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'user_register' : user_register})
```

my file users/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs = 
                {
                'class' : 'form-control', 
                'placeholder' : 'Ingresa un nombre de usuario'
                })
            'email' : forms.TextInput(attrs = 
                {
                'type' : 'email',
                'class' : 'form-control', 
                'placeholder' : 'Ingresa un email'
                })
            'password' : forms.TextInput(attrs = 
                {
                'type' : 'password',
                'class' : 'form-control', 
                'placeholder' : 'Ingresa un password'
                })
        }
```

my local.py is :

```
from .base import *
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'eventusdb',
        'USER': 'eventususer',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.child('media')
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Firstly, why don't you use an up-to-date tutorial? And what on Earth is that second entry in urls.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this `if settings.DEBUG:` block completely. It is replacing your `urlpatterns` with a single URL pattern for media files.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then add `static(...)` to the end of your `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^', include('myapps.events.urls', namespace="events_app")),
   ...
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```